# my C++ program works, even when I carefully modify it. But how?

Tags: c++11

I was under the impression that the C++ logical AND operator && evaluated from left to right in short circuit fashion. However, in the following program I understand everything except the condition within the if statement, which obviously evaluates to true through and through under most conditions as I have compiled and ran the program. It even works if I take out the entire if() statement minus the original content of course. It also produces the exact same results after having done this. It would seem to my probably lesser brain, or perhaps less experienced brain, that the constant pointer pArea, after having been passed the double Area, would cause the if condition to evaluate to false as the double Area is initialized to a value of zero BEFORE the CalcArea function preforms its calculation. Please tell me where my thinking has gone wrong, or is lacking Igor, this is not a typo in the book this time, the program compiles 
and runs. Thank you from the bottom of my heart, I LOVE C++. Please also explain to me how I can vote points on this site for you or request you be given some for of merit award. program follows:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void CalcArea(const double* const pPi, 
              const double* const pRadius, 
              double* const pArea)
{
  if (pPi && pRadius && pArea)
    *pArea = (*pPi) * (*pRadius) * (*pRadius);
}

int main()
{
  const double Pi = 3.1416;

  cout<< "enter radius of circle: ";
  double Radius = 0;
  cin>> Radius;

  double Area = 0;
  CalcArea (&Pi, &Radius, &Area);

  cout<< "area is = " <<Area<<endl;

  cout<< "press enter to continue..." <<endl;
  cin.ignore(10, '\n');
  cin.get();

  return 0;
}
```

Thank you again Igor, much appreciated, much respect from a fledgling programmer. Peace

Comment: Your question would be easier to understand if you leave out the chatty sections and add a more detailed explanation of what you are trying to do and what goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Pointer is evaluated to true if it's not nullptr (0). It doesn't matter what dereferenced value is.

Try

```
if (*pPi && *pRadius && *pArea)
```

Comment: It's hard to know what that if statement is supposed to accomplish. Is it checking for null? None of those pointers will be null given the way they are called. Is it checking for zero? *pArea will always be zero. References would be better than pointers anyhow.